# Where to put utility methods in Ruby superclass

Tags: ruby, inheritance, subclass, superclass, utility-method

I'm writing a Ruby object that will be used as the superclass of arbitrary classes that inherit from it. The class has a couple well-defined methods, along with many small utility methods, to factor out some work from the main methods. I want those methods to be invisible from subclasses, with no chance of causing naming conflicts. What is the best practice for this situation?

**Edit:** By "invisible", I mean that there won't accidentally be naming conflicts or invocations. I realize there will always be sneaky ways to get at class members.

Answer (score 0):

Make them private and name them `def __some_utility_method`

However, in Ruby nothing is really ever "invisible"